# return multiple array through json in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I want to return multiple array using json in codeigniter like this :

```
   {
         "countData"
             [
                 {"flag":1,"count":3}
                 {"flag":0,"count":0}
                 {"flag":1,"count":2}
             ]
     }
```

I already tried :

```
    $faqdata=array(
                       'count' => $faqdata['countdata']['resultdata']['count'],
                   )
     $listfaqcount['count_Data'][]=$faqdata;
     $listfaqcount['flag'] =1;
     $j_r=json_encode($listfaqcount);
     echo $j_r;
```

Like this way for two more array .`flag` would be zero in else condition which I didn't mention here.

How can I do this? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$listfaqcount['countData'][0] = array(
    'flag' => 'flagValue',
    'count' => 'countValue'
);
```

While you looping you change the index with your key like that

```
$listfaqcount['countData'][1] = array(
    'flag' => 'flagValue',
    'count' => 'countValue'
);
```

and so on and while you encoding you can do like this

```
echo json_encode($listfaqcount);
```

Comment: it doesn't work.here `countData` come in three time while  i want `countData` occurence only onece i.e it is an object in json terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `array_push`

```
$array['countdata'] = [];
```

create our sample array sets

```
$somearray1 = ['flag'=>9,"count"=>5];
$somearray2 = ['flag'=>6,"count"=>6];
$somearray3 = ['flag'=>5,"count"=>7];
$somearray4 = ['flag'=>4,"count"=>8];
```

Basically what happens here is everytime you loop you push the array inside `$array['countdata']`

```
array_push($array['countdata'], $somearray1); //loop 1 format and push
array_push($array['countdata'], $somearray2); //loop 2 format and push
array_push($array['countdata'], $somearray3); //loop 3 format and push
array_push($array['countdata'], $somearray4); //loop 4 format and push
```

Print the result beautifully or prettily

```
print_r(json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

result would be

```
{
    "countdata": [
        {
            "flag": 9,
            "count": 5
        },
        {
            "flag": 6,
            "count": 6
        },
        {
            "flag": 5,
            "count": 7
        },
        {
            "flag": 4,
            "count": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

this is just an example you could push your own formatted array.